# Use generic type as well as accept object with any keys

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to have the `Use` function argument type take any unknown key, as well as properly type the keys from `SomeGeneric`?

```
function Example (opt: { valid?: boolean }) {
}

type SomeGeneric = Parameters<typeof Example>[0]

function Use(opt: SomeGeneric) { 

}

Use({ valid: true }) // good
Use({ valid: 'true' }) // good
Use({ meow: true }) // doesn't take "unknown" options b/c `meow` is not in example

function UseAny(opt: SomeGeneric & any) { 

}

UseAny({ valid: 'hi', meow: true }) // doesn't correctly validate `valid` when string
```

How can I make `Use({ meow: true })` not throw a type warning.

Answer (score 1):

you need `object` here instead of `any`.

```js
function UseAny(opt: SomeGeneric & object) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is working here:

> Note: The only issue here is it loosens the types for the entire set, meaning something like this `Use({ VALID: 1 })` doesn't throw a type error.

```
function Example (opt: { valid?: boolean }) {
}

type SomeGeneric = Parameters<typeof Example>[0]

function Use(opt: SomeGeneric & { [others: string]: any }) { 

}

Use({ valid: true }) // good
Use({ valid: 'true' }) // good
Use({ meow: true }) // good
```